# Why doesn't work Wi-fi scanning in the background without location service on android 6.0?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, location-services

My question is very simple.
when device OS was Lolipop or kitkat or jellybean, i could get Wi-fi scan result in background without Location service well.(it means Location service turn off)
after OS upgrade to 6.0 Mashmallow, it doesn't work.

if i turn on the location service, i can get Wi-fi scan result in background on Android 6.0.

why it doesn't work? and
How i can get Wi-fi scan result in Background on 6.0.

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730781/android-wifimanager-getscanresult-complains-need-access-coarse-location-or-acces

Comment: I read already. Additionally my app already has permissions (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, CHANGE_WIFI_STATE and etc...)

Comment: Additionally. in case of OS 6.0, build target doesn't matter. any build target can't scan in background without location service. only foreground, device can scan without location service. (i tried test about build target : 18,19,21,22,23)

Comment: Hey, I'm in your shoes right now. Did you managed to scan wifi without location service turned on ?

Comment: Actually no. location service of android 6.0 contain the wifi always scanning. so. when location service turned off, wifi always scanning also turned off. In conclusion, we can't wifi scan in the background on android 6.0 without location service.